# "SKTexture: Error loading image resource" in Swift, Xcode version 9.4.1

Tags: swift, xcode

I am working on a game and the images that are in my Assets.Xcassets folder appear as a square with a red X in the middle when I build my game. The error that appears is **SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "food1, food2, food3, food4, food5"**

My code in class GameScene: SKScene,

I set a timer property and the images are listed in an array of string

```
var foodTimer:Timer!

var randomFood = ["food1, food2, food3, food4, food5"]
```

My code in "didMove(to view: SKView)"

foodTimer will allow food to appear on screen every 0.75 seconds

```
foodTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.75, target: self, selector: #selector(addFood), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

My code in my another function that is after "didMove(to view: SKView)"

```
@objc func addFood() {

    randomFood = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: randomFood) as! [String]

    let food = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: randomFood[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a [String] with just one entry I imagine you meant a to do ["food1", ...] not ["food1, ..."]?

Comment: Wow, I need to pay attention to detail more. Thanks for your help!